# How to make solr suggestion work for a specific field?

Tags: solr, autosuggest

I am trying to implement the auto suggest of solr  this is the changes that I made in solrconfig.xml file

```
<requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/suggest">
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
</lst>
<arr name="components">
  <str>suggest</str>
</arr>
</requestHandler>
<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
<lst name="spellchecker">
  <str name="name">suggest</str>
  <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
  <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookupFactory</str>
  <str name="field">displayName</str>  <!-- the indexed field to derive suggestions from -->
  <float name="threshold">0.005</float>
  <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
</lst>
</searchComponent>
```

when I try to query with sample input as 'p'

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/food/suggest?q=p&wt=json&indent=true
```

it returns 5 words

`"pizza", "potato", "pasta", "protein", "premium"`

but in the displayName field I got words like paneer , palak etc which is not showing up why is it so?

Comment: field : A field from the index to use as the basis of suggestion terms.

Comment: yes i have mentioned my field

Comment: are you looking for more than five result then provide update the default configuration `<str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>`. You can also pass the parameter in your query command `&suggest.count=10`.

Comment: you are not referrring the suggestre name in the url?oops you are passing.. try abhishek's suggestion

Comment: Try this `http://localhost:8983/solr/food/suggest?q=p&wt=json&indent=true&suggest.count=10`

Comment: I am sorry that's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you added the following to your configuration and run the below query. **Don't forget to reload the solr core after putting these changes.**

```
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
<str name="storeDir">suggester_fuzzy_dir</str>
```

`http://localhost:8983/solr/food/suggest?suggest=true&suggest.build=true&suggest.dictionary=suggest&wt=json&suggest.q=p&suggest.count=10`

Comment: It's not working i even tried reindexing the whole data but it isn't